# Artifactory server throwing error: Service unavailable

Tags: artifactory

I am hosting the artifactory application over an AWS EC2 instance behind a load balancer.
I was facing the error "502 Bad gateway",and as there was full memory issue with the instance thus have increased the instance memory and restarted the artifactory service. Since then we are facing issue with the artifactory service as " Service Unavailable".
I have tried below:

1.Rebooting the server and restarting the artifactory service.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyqiV.png)

2. On verifying the logs for artifactory, found this on frontend-services.log:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI4i8.png)
3. Running the localhost command to verify the local connectivity, however it is also not working:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g5Xj.png)

Looking for a solution that could help in fixing this issue.

Here are the logs from artifactory-service.log file :
@MuhammedKashif , here is the error:

```java
2021-11-09T11:36:39.194Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [91df69516c99cd8f] [ifactoryApplicationContext:261] [art-init            ] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bowerRepositoryTypeHelper': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repositoryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'aclService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'accessConverters'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accessConverters' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/artifactory-core-7.6.3.jar!/org/artifactory/security/access/emigrate/AccessConverters.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'v6600CreateDefaultBuildAcl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setInternalBuildService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'buildServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUploadService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'uploadServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setBinaryService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'binaryServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
2021-11-09T11:36:39.204Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [91df69516c99cd8f] [ctoryContextConfigListener:116] [art-init            ] - Application could not be initialized: No content to map to Object dueto end of input
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)

*** 
Here are the logs from tomcat:
09-Nov-2021 11:34:20.843 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
09-Nov-2021 11:34:20.847 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
09-Nov-2021 11:34:20.855 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8091"]
09-Nov-2021 11:34:20.858 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8040"]
09-Nov-2021 11:34:20.865 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
09-Nov-2021 11:34:26.433 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
09-Nov-2021 11:34:26.446 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8091"]
09-Nov-2021 11:34:26.484 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8040"]
09-Nov-2021 11:34:26.530 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
09-Nov-2021 11:34:26.539 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8091"]
09-Nov-2021 11:34:26.555 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8040"]
09-Nov-2021 11:35:31.899 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
09-Nov-2021 11:35:31.923 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
09-Nov-2021 11:35:31.941 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8091"]
09-Nov-2021 11:35:31.942 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
09-Nov-2021 11:35:31.944 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8040"]
09-Nov-2021 11:35:31.944 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
09-Nov-2021 11:35:31.968 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
09-Nov-2021 11:35:31.969 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.55
09-Nov-2021 11:35:32.007 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/access.xml]
09-Nov-2021 11:35:32.007 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml]
09-Nov-2021 11:35:32.065 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor A docBase [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory.war] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
09-Nov-2021 11:35:32.065 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor A docBase [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access.war] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
09-Nov-2021 11:35:37.694 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml] has finished in [5,683] ms
09-Nov-2021 11:35:47.458 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/access.xml] has finished in [15,451] ms
09-Nov-2021 11:35:47.459 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
09-Nov-2021 11:35:47.495 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [35] ms
09-Nov-2021 11:35:47.499 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
09-Nov-2021 11:35:47.516 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8091"]
09-Nov-2021 11:35:47.518 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8040"]
09-Nov-2021 11:36:01.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
09-Nov-2021 11:36:01.612 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
```

Comment: According to the error in the `frontend-service.log`, it got `500` from Artifactory. Did you look in the `artifactory-service.log`? It probably has an error there.

Comment: The artifactory-service.log is showing : 
2021-11-02T19:25:09.942Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [                ] [o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryFilter:201 ] [27.0.0.1-8091-exec-1] - Artifactory failed to initialize: Context is null.

However, the service artifactory is showing up and running

Comment: Then Artifactory is not really running, only Tomcat... Try to look in the Tomcat's logs for the root cause.

Comment: What does the "caused by" of the "Artifactory failed to initialize: Context is null." says? Can you share here?

Comment: @MuhammedKashif , here is the error:

Comment: Still the error is not clear. Can you please paste the entire error stacktrace? The stacktrace should include the "caused by" clause in it. Basically, scroll down the error and look for the "caused by" and share with me :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have encountered the 502 error due to network issues.

If you have a reverse proxy setup, please try to bypass the proxy next time this behavior reproduces and let me know if you were able to reach Artifactory UI (to bypass the proxy simply use Artifactory IP - http://<Artifactory_IP>:8081).